# useRef in typescript returning a boolean

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm developing an app with `Nextjs` and I've some issue using react useRef with typescript. When using useRef without typescript everything is fine, but when using it with `HTMLDivEleement` as a generic type parameter, it returns me a boolean type. It's not only a type at compile-time issue, but at the run time my ref is indeed a boolean.

Here is my code :

```
import React from "react";

export const MenuSystem = () => {
    const buttonContainerRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    console.log("container ref", buttonContainerRef);

    return <div ref={buttonContainerRef}></div>;
};
```

Here my `buttonContainerRef` is a `boolean` equal to `false`.

Of course, I get the "Function components cannot have string refs. We recommend using `useRef()` instead." error as well.

Here are my dependencies, just in case it helps:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu": "^0.1.3",
    "@radix-ui/react-portal": "^0.1.3",
    "framer-motion": "^5.4.5",
    "next": "^12.0.7",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.4.9",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.4.9",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.4.9",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.4.9",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.12",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.37",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "typescript": "^4.5.3"
  }
```

Comment: print out `log(HTMLDivElement)`, see what this is ? the ref in your case can never be a string, it's in a format of `{ current: ... }` after intialization.

Comment: `buttonContainerRef` is `React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>`. See [here](https://tsplay.dev/wEGq3m). Also try to install `@types/react`

Comment: There is no issue I get when I created a sandbox with exact same versions. https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-rumple-7p6hm?file=/src/App.tsx. It logs `container ref {current: HTMLDivElement} current: <div></div>`

Comment: @windmaomao yeah i know, that's the issue I've. the format I get is not { current: ... }

@captain-yossarian I know `React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>` is the type it should be, but for a weird reason it's not a compile and runtime.

@AmilaSenadheera thx for testing it ! Maybe it's an issue with next itself ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the reason was that my project was not using typescript. `React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)` would then be parsed as a comparison expression, which of course returns a boolean value.